# Push value from input to object array and update tab names labels- Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-material, tabs, ngfor

I have a reactive form and I am using Material Angular, with a tab group and the tab names comes from an array, I need to add the possibility of changing those tabs names for new ones. If a write a new title in the input I need to update the name of the tab label.

I’m getting the value from the input, but I can’t figure it out how to send it to the names of the tabs:

**app.component.ts**

```
this.newTitleArm = selection.formdata.titleTextArms;
console.log(this.newTitleArm);
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-components-demo-qpulen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpD6q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you have a look at this [Stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-components-demo-sx9dhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)

Note that I have modified the submit method and have added

```
if(this.form.get('titleArms').value === 'changeArm'){
  this.tabs[this.selected.value].name = this.form.get('titleTextArms').value;
}
```

Here I'm assigning the **titleTextArms** control value to selected tab name. You can get selected tab by **this.tabs[this.selected.value]**

Also added the if condition to check selection of radio button.

UPDATE:

since you have used tab names to create the text in the parent component.

In the submit method

need to do the tab name update before emitting the **updateDataEvent**.

```
 submit(): void {

    if (this.form.get('titleArms').value === 'changeArm') {
      if (this.form.get('titleTextArms').value !== '') {
        this.tabs[this.selected.value].name =
          this.form.get('titleTextArms').value;
      }
    }

    this.updateDataEvent.emit({
      formdata: this.form.getRawValue(),
      tabs: this.tabs,
    });

    
  }
```

Comment: Oh thanks!  I understand much better now. One more question, do you know know why is this happening? 
I have to click the ‘Save’ button two times to see the new tab tittle in the parent component (I added a screenshot in the description). Maybe cause I have a updateDataEvent in the child.component.ts ?  [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-components-demo-prfsqt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)

Comment: oh thanks! the solution was so simple haha

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not updating the respective `tab` name anywhere, neither in your `submit`, nor in your `updateData`.

You submit the value, but you are not updating the `tabs`.

For example, in your `submit` method add this hard-coded update and then press the Save button:

```
this.tabs[0].name = "test";
```

Because now you updated the first tab's name, you should see the change.

Comment: Your example works, but I don't understand where should I add this code this.newTitleArm = selection.formdata.titleTextArms; in order to update the name of the tag with the text that the user can write on the input. I have it inside the submit but not working.

Comment: @bel Like I said in my answer, this won't work, because again you are not updating `tabs`. You need to identify the associated `tab` and update its name! That's because you are looping on `tabs` and you are using `tab.name` as the displayed name value of the tab. I don't see how the variable you're updating with the line you quoted is relevant.